# What is the best way to redirect based on token and url? React-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

This is my router:

```
const Router = () => {
  const { user } = useContext(UserContext)

  return (
    <Switch>
      {user.token ?
        <>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Wall}/>
          <Route path="/profile" component={Profile}/>
          <Route path="/discover" component={Discover}/>
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
          <Route path="/post" component={Post}/>
          <Route path="/deleteuser" component={DeleteUser}/>
          <Route path="/profileimg" component={ProfileImg}/> 
        </> :
        <>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Splash}/>
          <Route path="/auth" component={Auth}/>
          <Route path="/create" component={Create}/>
          <Route path="/forgot" component={Forgot}/>
        </>
      }
      {!user.token && <Redirect to="/"/>}
      <Route component={Notfound}/>
    </Switch>
  )
}
```

As you can see I have protected routs based on whether the user has a token in context.

In my app, I have a function `logout()` that clears local storage and state information which of course includes the user token.

My problem is I can't seem to find any documentation on the best way to redirect to `"/"` if the user is on a protected route and this `logout()` function is called.

To be clear what I want is this: `logout()` => `<Redirect to="/"/>` because there is no longer a token in state.

I have thought of multiple ways of doing this BUT I'm looking for the best or cleanest solution:

1. An approach using history - `history.location.pathname === "/protected" && !user.token && <Redirect to="/"/>` I'm sure there is a way to achive the same logic this with `<Redirect/>` in my router?
2. An approach using redirect in the JSX of every single protected component - `{!user.token && <Redirect to="/"/>}` I would rather not put this in the component JSX of every single protected route I have!
3. I could pass the history prop to the `logout()` function and do this - `history && history.push("/")` I would also rather not do this as I would need to pass the history prop every time I call `logout()` which feels rather messy.

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a route `<Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout}/>`.

with

```
export default const Logout = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    //remove token here
  }, []);

  return <Redirect to="/">
}
```

or a function logout with transition to your home like

```
const history = useHistory();
const logout = () => {
  // remove tokens
  history.push('/');
}
```

or both

```
const logout = () => {
  // remove tokens
  return <Redirect to="/"/>
}
```

Comment: I would love for the second option to work however `logout()` is not a component. It's a vanilla js function. history from useHistory() is a hook that can only be used within the body of a component.

Comment: I think you can't do a react transition without using the react router history or redirect...

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do anything inside router.js or `logout()` in the end. I instead used an approach that obviously had escaped my mind at the time of this post.

In order to redirect with React, we need a way to trigger a rerender. I'm can't be sure if all of the methods discussed above do in fact rerender however the default way of achieving this in a React is to update Context or your store state if you're using Redux. Then based on that state, in a component you know is always going to be rendered, add some code to redirect.

This is my code in `Nav`:

```
const Nav = ({ history }) => {
  const { user, setUser } = useContext(UserContext)

  useEffect(() => { // Redirect if user.redirect === truthy.
    user.redirect && history.push(user.redirect)
    setUser({ ...user, redirect: false })
  }, [user.redirect]) // eslint-disable-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  *** rest of the code in Nav ***
}
```